# selenium maven tests work on local machine but not on Jenkins

Tags: java, maven, selenium, jenkins, webdriver

I have some tests in selenium. When I run them using maven on my local machine then everything works fine, but when I try to start them using jenkins I get an error. Can anyone help me out and tell why it works on my machine, and doesnt on Jenkins? Thanks

```
[SNOWDEN_develop_Selenium_AutoTests] $ java -cp /var/lib/jenkins/maven33-agent.jar:/var/lib/jenkins/tools/hudson.tasks.Maven_MavenInstallation/maven  /boot/plexus-classworlds-2.5.2.jar:/var/lib/jenkins/tools  /hudson.tasks.Maven_MavenInstallation/maven/conf/logging  jenkins.maven3.agent.Maven33Main /var/lib/jenkins/tools/hudson.tasks.Maven_MavenInstallation/maven /var/lib/jenkins/slave.jar /var/lib/jenkins/maven33-interceptor.jar /var/lib/jenkins/maven3-interceptor-commons.jar 43010
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:  hudson.remoting.Launcher
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass(SelfFirstStrategy.java:50)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.unsynchronizedLoadClass(ClassRealm.java:271)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:247)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:239)
at jenkins.maven3.agent.Maven33Main.main(Maven33Main.java:133)
at jenkins.maven3.agent.Maven33Main.main(Maven33Main.java:64)
[SNOWDEN_develop_Selenium_AutoTests] $ /bin/bash -xe /tmp/hudson5734623695552292225.sh
+ cd /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/SNOWDEN_develop_Selenium_AutoTests/snowden-docker
+ ./docker.snowden.sh stop devsel
WORKSPACE: /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/SNOWDEN_develop_Selenium_AutoTests 
Docker host : 10.0.0.27:4243 (SNOWDEN-DEV)
Stop docker container snowden_devsel ... 
Stoping container snowden_devsel ... 
snowden_devsel_tomcat
snowden_devsel_mongodb
ERROR: Failed to parse POMs
java.io.EOFException: unexpected stream termination
at hudson.remoting.ChannelBuilder.negotiate(ChannelBuilder.java:365)
at hudson.remoting.ChannelBuilder.build(ChannelBuilder.java:310)
at hudson.slaves.Channels.forProcess(Channels.java:115)
at hudson.maven.AbstractMavenProcessFactory.newProcess(AbstractMavenProcessFactory.java:294)
at hudson.maven.ProcessCache.get(ProcessCache.java:236)
at   hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$MavenModuleSetBuildExecution.doRun(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:798)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:534)
at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1728)
at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild.run(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:544)
at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:404)
Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: Looks like the classpath constructed by Jenkins fails to include the jar that contains the class `hudson.remoting.Launcher`. It seems (I looked it up on findjar.com) that class can be found in `remoting-<version>.jar` or `hudson-core-<version>.jar`.

Comment: What does it mean? What should I do? Sorry but I don't understand what I should do now :(

Comment: Or the cause might be the other exception that says there is a parse error in your POM file.